# Jquery, reference error SharePoint2013

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

hi im writing some code that gets back a users name using jquery and handlebars within SharePoint 2013. I have created a test account and I'm trying to retrieve the profiles details, however i'm getting an issue "uncaught reference error (function) is not defined. I've commented the line on which my issue occurs.

```
; (function ($, window, document, undefined) {

//creates the default data
var pluginName = "DisplayUserData",
defaults = {
    user: null
    };

//plugin ctor
function DisplayUserData(element, options) {
var that = this;

that.element = element;
that.$element = jQuery(element);

that.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
that.defaults = defaults;

that.styleLibraryPath = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/SiteAssets/userdata/displaydata";

that.init();
}

DisplayUserData.prototype = {
init: function () {
    var that = this;


    if(typeof that.options.user != null) {
        var templateCall = that.getTemplate(that.options.template);

        templateCall.complete(function (date) {
            that.mix(data);    //here is my issue
            });
        }
    },

getTemplate: function (template) {
    var that = this;
    return jQuery.ajax({
        url: that.styleLibraryPath +"/" + template,
        type: "GET",
        cache: true,
        data: {},
        dataType: "html",
        contentType: "text/html"
        });
    },

mix: function (data) {
    var that = this;
        template = data,
        results = that.getValueByKey(that.options.property, that.options.user);
    if (results !== "" && typeof results != 'undefined') {
        that.display(results, template);
        }
    },

getValueByKey: function (key, obj) {
var data = jQuery.grep(obj.UserProfileProperties, function (item) {
return item.Key == key;
});

if (data.length > 0) {
    var value = data[0].Value;
    if (key === "Title") {
        var titleSegments = value.split(" ");
        value = titleSegments[titleSegments.length - 1];
        }
        return value;
    }
},

display: function (results, template) {
    var that = this;
    var compiledTemplate = Handlebars.compile(template);
    var outputHtml = compiledTemplate(results);
    that.$element.html(outputHtml);
    }
};

//plugin wrapper prventing multiple instantiations

$.fn[pluginName] = function (options) {
    return this.each(function () {
    $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName,
    new DisplayUserData(this, options));
    });
};
}) (jQuery, window, document);
```

Comment: console.log the variable "that" and see what it is.

Comment: that is "this" just made personal to that method rather than global. that.mix(data) the (data) is what is throwing my problem.
When I ran console.log(that) nothing was returned, as I would expect, but running console.log(data) should return data